# Image not updated in item added to custom list

Tags: c#, collections

I have a item with Image field, and a custom list derived from CollectionBase. When I add the item to the custom list, and then try to change that item Image and then get the item from the list, the Image is not set on the list item.
How to make sure that the item in the list is the same as the item we created and any update will be sync between the two.

Comment: Hi Priyank, Its not completely clear what you mean, could you post a code snippet of what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your item a value type or a reference type ?

If the item is a struct, getting an item from the list will actually get a copy, you have to change that copy, remove the original and reinsert it in the list.